# Find the configuration of on/off switches that maximizes number of light bulbs turned on

Tags: algorithm

I have a collection $C$ of unique binary 1-dimensional vectors of length $n$, so there are $2^{n-1}$ elements in this collection excluding the one with all $0$'s. It's not exactly a powerset because all items are the same length, but I used a powerset to create this and appended $0$'s in an appropriate way. For example, when $n = 3$,

0 0 1

0 1 0

0 1 1

1 0 0

1 0 1

1 1 0

1 1 1

Each element has an associated reward function $R$ where $R(v) \ge 0$ for $v \in C$. Also, it's possible $R(v) \ge n$.

These are my current observations on $R$ (percentages are not exact, but representative):

1. $R(v) = 0$ like $80$% of the time
2. $R(v) = 10$ like $19$% of
   the time
3. $R(v) > 10$ like $1$% of the time

In short, most of the items in this collection will not provide a useful reward. The rewards are not random, but I don't know how to find out what distribution they follow. What is the best way to maximize this reward without having to go through all 2^n-1 elements?

Let me rephrase the question with an example.

I think of $C$ as a collection of on/off switch configurations and each configuration turns on a number of light bulbs (one switch != one light bulb, for example, 0010 can turn on 0 light bulbs, and 0110 can turn on 5 lightbulbs). What's the fastest way to find the maximum number of light bulbs turned on if

1. hardly any of these configurations will turn on a light-bulb,
2. very few light bulbs turn on more than 10 light bulbs, but there are a few configurations that can turn on 100's of light bulbs .

I tried using a variation of Viterbi (using a cumulative sum of rewards instead of probabilities) in which I keep track of how changing a single element will yield a maximal result, but I think an implementation of Branch and Bound or a decision tree would be better in this case. A genetic algorithm would not work because the distribution of the rewards is too biased towards 0 and 10. And a brute-force approach for one at a time would take forever if $n$ is large.

Any suggestions? I will have to code this up but I want to get a feel for a solution.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the question is essentially, "Is there a way to find the maximum value in an unsorted array in less than O(n) time?" The answer is, "No, unless there's some information shared between elements." BTW, mathjax doesn't work on this site, so using it makes the question all but unreadable.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the noisy formatting characters. In the top-right corner of the editing box, there's a question mark icon. Click on that and you'll get information on the Markdown markup language that's used here.